# Toggling visibility of div block in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a navigation bar like the attached image.

I want to hide the sub categories and display when a main category is clicked.

My HTML is-

```
<div class="mainlink">
<h4><a href="#">Germany</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="sublink" hidden>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">League 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">League 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="mainlink">
<h4><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="sublink" hidden>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">League 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">League 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried using the following JS, but I am unable to display the sub categories on click of main categories. What should I add or change?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('item').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.sublink').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
</script>
```

[image: Sample layout image]

Comment: Change the selector `'.mainlink'` instead of `item`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like `item` exist in your HTML.

You need to use `class` or `id` selector there.

In your case it need to be `class` selector:-
 `$('.mainlink').click(function() {`:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mainlink').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.sublink').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

```css
.visible{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainlink">
<h4><a href="#">Germany</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="sublink" hidden>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">League 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">League 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="mainlink">
<h4><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="sublink" hidden>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">League 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">League 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note:- it's important to add jQuery library before your script code (to make it run). So add that (I have added it in my example.)

Comment: Judging by OP's problem, OP seems to be beginner and I would have made answer more explanatory, but this seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

Correct your selector `mainlink`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mainlink').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.sublink').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
.visible{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainlink">
  <h4><a href="#">Germany</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="sublink" hidden>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">League 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">League 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="mainlink">
  <h4><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="sublink" hidden>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">League 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">League 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
$('item').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.sublink').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

but there is nothing like `item' in your html. So change it to:

```
$('.mainlink').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.sublink').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

as `<div class="mainlink">` has `mainlink` class in it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the selector `item` change that into `.mainlink` It will be working

**`.`** is used to access the items with `class name` 
`.mainlink`

You need to use **id** or **class name** for as selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mainlink').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.sublink').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

```css
.visible{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainlink">
<h4><a href="#">Germany</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="sublink" hidden>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">League 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">League 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="mainlink">
<h4><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="sublink" hidden>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">League 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">League 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```